# nWidart/laravel-modules How Use Config key modules in my view

Tags: laravel

I use nWidart/laravel-modules package, I need to use myModulesName Config keys in view.
My config path : `Modules\Tickets\Config\config.php`
and my config.php is:

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => 'Tickets',

    'status' => [
        '1' => 'باز',
        '2' => 'درحال بررسی',
        '3' => 'بسته شده'
    ],
    'color' => [
        '1' => 'label-danger',
        '2' => 'label-warning',
        '3' => 'label-success',
    ],
];
```

now, in my view, how I can use config keys?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this config.php file to config folder with another name like `tickets.php` and get value like this:

```
{{ config('tickets.name') }}
```

Before that run this command `php artisan config:cache`

To use package which is in another folder [Follow this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#resources)

Comment: you said "Add this config.php file to config folder". add this file to "myproject\config" folder or "myproject\Modules\Tickets\Config" folder ?

Comment: myproject\config folder

Comment: ok this worked, but i use nWidart/laravel-modules, and this package include config file in myproject\Modules\Tickets\Config", i need use for this solution !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
return [
  'name' => 'Blog',
  'fa_name' => 'وبلاگ',
  'icon' => 'comment',
  'color1' => 'EF6F6C',
  'color2' => 'EF6F6C',
  'route' => 'blog',
  'disable' => false,

  'subs' => [
    ['name' => 'مطالب وبلاگ', 'route' => 'blog/list'],
    ['name' => 'دسته بندی ها', 'route' => 'category/list']
  ]
];
```